# Why does a list slice [:n] allow using a list with fewer than n elements in a loop?

Tags: python, list, slice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [good primer for python slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

I have this Python code; `items` is a list of tuples:

```
# Print the first 20
for item in items[:20]:
    print item[0], item[1]
```

It prints the first twenty elements of the list. If the list has fewer than twenty elements, it still works, but I don't understand why. How do I interpret it?

Comment: `items[:20]` is a *slice*, as [described elsewhere on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation). Essentially, this takes *up to* the first twenty items of the list, ensuring that even if there are not enough items, the slice will not fail with an exception.

Comment: I was confused by the : at the end which is acting as the start of for loop

Comment: @vaichidrewar the first part when omitted means the start, 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the passed value exceeds the number of list elements, slice is limited by the length of the list.

```
l = range(1,2)
l[:10] == l
```